# Foursquare Venues/Explore API: SIghts

Tags: foursquare

The Foursquare venues/explore API, section parameter is not functioning well for me.

When specifying "sights" under the section parameter, I get many things, including food venues that shouldn't be there. I do not have this problem when specifying food, arts, outdoors, etc.

You can test this out by changing the section parameter here:

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/explore%3Fll%3D40.7,-74%26section%3Doutdoors

...and looking for the ['response']['query'] result. It is non-existent when you specify "sights".

Does anyone have a workaround? I would like to use the venues/explore endpoint because of the sortbydistance parameter.

Comment: I'm having trouble replicating this issue. Are you still experiencing this? What are some venues being returned that you aren't expecting?

Comment: @enc_life Here's an example - looking for sights around NYC. https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&v=20150726&intent=browse&ll=40.7127837,-74.0059413&radius=20000&limit=100&venuePhotos=1&time=any&day=any&section=sights . Since I specified "sights", I don't want to see all of the restaurants.  Besides that, I would expect to see a better listing of "sights" in NYC than what is returned... seems arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

The `section=sights` parameter should return venues that people tend to visit when they are traveling to a new area. These are generally over-indexed to things like parks and monuments but will also contain restaurants and bars if they're worth visiting.

These results aren't curated so you won't they won't be like a traditional guide-book (empire state building, statue of liberty, etc) but provide a unique perspective based on people that travel to and live in the area.

If you're interested in tourist specific things try removing the `section` parameter and use a `query` term of `tourist` or whatever you're trying to achieve. The `venues/explore` endpoint is pretty good at parsing query terms into meaningful results.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue, and I am afraid it's because Foursquare is trying to promote those restaurants..

My idea is simple, do another query with `section=food` and remove each of this if it is in `sights`.

---

Another idea is checking if `'food' in ['venue']['categories'][0]['icon']['prefix']` also `nightlife` shouldn't be in `sights`as well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using venues/explore end point by not specify **section** value with this query parameter

> **query=tourist**
>
> // plus other parameters e.g. ll, radius

This combination give me attraction places where traveller mostly travel to. So far I don't see much restaurants in the results.